# ImportError: No module named 'myproject.settings'

Tags: django, openshift, importerror

I was running nicely a Django python project on Openshift. But from the moment that I tried to create and push a 'requirements.txt' file to be able to include the 'requests' library, the problems started to come:

ImportError: No module named 'myproject.settings'

Even after deleting the requirements.txt file again, this errormessage stayed .

Can someone help me please?

This is how my structure looks like :

[screenshot file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWGv0.jpg)

And this is what can be found in my 'Application' file

```
## GETTING-STARTED: make sure the next line points to your settings.py:
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
## GETTING-STARTED: make sure the next line points to your django project dir:
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi', 'myproject'))
```

And here is a screenshot of the tail log on the server :
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH7F7.png)

Comment: Can you show the contents of the requirements file?

Comment: I deleted the requirements.txt file on my local pc and suppose this action is also pushed to the openshift server.

Comment: Not necessarily. Did you commit and push the changes?

Comment: Hi @HaraldNordgren , thanks for helping !

Comment: I just checked the server using FileZilla and there was no requirements.txt anymore. Somehow the reference 'myproject.settings' towards the filestructure 'wsgi/myproject/myproject/settings.py' does not get resolved anymore. When I move 'settings.py' one level up, the error shifts to a similar error towards 'urls.py'. So somehow something got screwed up.

I rolled back this to a version before I created the requirements.txt file, but still wonder what went wrong.

Comment: @HaraldNordgren , do you know a good way to launch pip on OpenShift for some new libraries (eg Requests) ? Should I dare to use requirements.txt file again (not yet existing when starting a Django app), or can I do something with the setup file (also not existing yet) ?